# Laravel guzzle Get request to API , interaction

Tags: php, laravel, api, get, guzzle

I'm trying to send get request to this API https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/ and it's working fine, i'm getting the object but when i try to call object properties it's giving me error:

```
Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::$id
```

This is my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/']);
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'bitcoin');  
    return $response->id;;
```

I don't really know how to interact with this object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guzzle Response object doesn't work that way, it doesn't assume what the response content is and proxy your request for a property.

You used to be able to call `$response->json()`, but you can't do that anymore due to PSR-7. Instead do something like this:

```
$items = json_decode($response->getBody());
foreach ($items as $item) {
     echo($item->id);
}
```

That endpoint returns an array of objects. So you would need to either get the first one or loop through them if there are multiple.

NOTE: If you are adding the namespace at the top of your controller like:

```
use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

You then in your code need only to refer to it as `Client` like:

```
$client = new Client(...);
```

Comment: That did it ! Thanks, i'll select your answer as soon as i can (in 3 minutes)

Comment: I did that request from web.php file just to test it, but when i try it from my controller it gives me error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found   Even though i just copy pasted code and i have use GuzzleHttp\Client;  so can you please help ne with that ?

Comment: I did , i have use GuzzleHttp\Client; but still the same , that is what's confusing me

Comment: `use \GuzzleHttp\Client;` -- needs that leading slash.

Comment: Still the same ... `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`

Comment: See my edit. You are improperly using the class name based on how you imported it.